# Load data from database on click + Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, database, zend-framework

I want to load data from the database when i click on an a link.
My links are data from a database. This is how I do it in my view:

```
<div id="wijken">
              <ul>
            <?php foreach($this->districts as $districts) : ?>
              <li><a><?php echo $this->escape($districts->wijk); ?></a></li>       
            <?php endforeach; ?>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Now I want that when you click on a link that I can load data and show data from the database depending on the link you clicked. How can I do this?

I tried it with javascript. Is it possible that you can load data with ajax call to an action in a controller?

My javascript:

```
$("#wijken ul li a").click(function(e){  

var wijk = ($(this).text());

$.ajax({ 

  type: "POST",
  url: "index/test",                    
  data: "wijk",                        

  dataType: 'json',                
  success: function(rows)          
  {
      alert("worked!");

  }, 
  error: function(error){
      alert("didn't worked!");
  }

  });
```

Could this work or not?

Comment: "Could this work or not?" So try and you will get answer...

Comment: I didn't work, i get always error. But maybe it's my testaction that doesn't work. I want to know if it's possible to do this before I check that.

Comment: alert("didn't worked!"); ... ajax call error

Comment: Check your php_error log what says?  you can find path to error_log in phpinfo() or you can call your Ajax action to see error(maybe), just in browser type localhost/project/index/test/wijk and ypu will see json string or error

Comment: Nothing about this error

Comment: your data param in JS is wring... check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489447/949273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer can help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489447/949273

It is a simple example of using Zend Framework and Ajax(JQuery).

Comment: Please do not vote up this answer. Vote up real answer on link.