# how do I call a function from a controller using ajax(jquery) in zend?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

This is my try  and this is executed by `onclick` event !

```
var post_array = {
    data_post: postData
}; //Array 
$.ajax({
    url: "location/add-names",
    type: "POST",
    data: post_array,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php

class LocationController extends \Lunchbox\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     ...................
    }
    public function addNamesAction(){
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

Route :

```
 $location = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('locatie/:locationUrl/:day', 
            array('module'     => 'default', 'controller' => 'location', 'day' => Cronos::getCurrentDayName()),
            array('day' => Cronos::$weekDayRegex)
        );
        $router->addRoute('location', $location);
```

I want to display "1" after the ajax event. But the firebug show me this error: "404 Not Found". I'm a newbie in zend so please give me a reasonable answer. Thx :D

now the debug.log shows me this :

```
2014-04-14T09:57:09+03:00 CRIT (2): ----------------
2014-04-14T09:57:09+03:00 CRIT (2): URL: /location/add-names
2014-04-14T09:57:09+03:00 CRIT (2): script 'location/add-names.phtml' not found in path (/home/lunchbox/public_html/application/views/scripts/)
#0 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(884): Zend_View_Abstract->_script('location/add-na...')
#1 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(900): Zend_View_Abstract->render('location/add-na...')
#2 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(921): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('location/add-na...', NULL)
#3 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(960): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#4 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#5 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(527): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#6 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('addNamesAction')
#7 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#8 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#9 /opt/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#10 /home/lunchbox/public_html/index.php(31): Zend_Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

cand someone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you added this route to your module.config.php? Or are you using other restrictions like an ACL?

Comment: please check my post again

Comment: try giving only `addNames` in the url of ajax if not working take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485726/using-jquery-to-post-data-in-zend-framework/8489447#8489447

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I can see here.

1. The route you have shown is for '/locatie/:locationUrl/:day' however the route you need is for '/location/add-names
2. in the ajax - the camel case that you use would indicate a url of add-names . the uppercase letter splits the url with a -

Hope that helps

Comment: thx man , but now im not getting the 404 error, im getting this: "500 Internal Server Error", any ideea or tips , why ? thx