# Zend Framework 2, How to send Json from View to Controller using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, zend-framework2

I'm following Album tutorial on Zend Framework 2's website, and I want to send object that have been converted to Json and pass controller via AJAX, I can invoke the method on the controller as well as receive Json from controller, but I don't know how to send parameter to it.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Provide what you have tried yet. This will increase the probabilityto get your answer .

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489447/949273

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pushing parameters to your controller via AJAX, like this?

```
 $.post('/your/url', { value: val, row: row, element: element }, //parameters
 function (ret) {

});
```